# how to create a controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am new to laravel and creating my first controller in this , i have created a file in directory **app/controllers/ContactController.php** and the code is

```
class ContactController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        echo "hieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee";
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


}
```

but if i hit url http://localhost:8000/contact it is showing me the error **We need a map.** am i missing something???please help me.

**update**

i also tried to add  Route::get('contact', "contact@index"); in my routes.php.

i setup an user log in and register module through git-hub and it is working perfectly if i hit url **http://localhost:8000/user/login**

**Update**

my laravel version is **laravel 4**

output in console is **39023 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)**

Comment: do you have a namespace?

Comment: Please read the documentation. Specifically on controllers and routing: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing

Comment: @lukasgeiter i have studied this but no effect.

Comment: why -ve??? i am saying i am new to this...

Comment: Then study it again. The third sentence on the controllers chapter says: *Controllers are typically stored in the `app/Http/Controllers` directory.* which you already didn't do.

Comment: here is no such type of directory , and my all controllers are in app/controllers/ directory

Comment: Sounds like you're using Laravel 4. If you're just starting out you should really switch to Laravel 5, the newest version.

Comment: yes i am usinng laravel 4

Comment: I recommend to watch the laracast tutorial videos to get an overview  about the basics of laravel! See here: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a problem with your route.

If you want to point to a single method from a controller, then you have to specify a `fullControllerName@methodName` convention.

Fix your route in `routes.php` as:

```
Route::get('contact', "contactController@index");
```

Also please follow good class naming convention while using OOP.

1. Controller class name shold start with capital letter.
2. It should contain Controller at end.

So do fix by renaming your controller class name as well as controller file name, and do:

```
Route::get('contact', "ContactController@index");
```

And by easy way, do it by command line by running:

```
php artisan make:controller ContactController
```

Comment: if you want useful feedback, you should provide the same. what exactly is happening now? This Answer solves the issues i saw too, so maybe there is something else?

Comment: i am not getting the output from my controller , 404 not found error @nozzleman

Comment: [Mon Mar  9 19:01:11 2015] 127.0.0.1:39023 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
this is the console output

Comment: @ris note that the port number is a different one than the one provided in your question (8000 vs 39023)...

Comment: @ris: may be there's some problem with your configurations, you should cross check it by starting from scratch. Make a new laravel project - create controller through command line - point the route - check the URL.

Comment: i have created the contact controller through command line .@RavirajChauhan

Comment: @nozzleman the port displaying in the terminal changes every time . when i start the laravel server with php artisan serve command then the output is   Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000

Comment: In laravel 5, it's`make:controller`

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with the things @Raviraj Chauhan already pointed out. in addition, i want to add that your file seems to have a typo which can cause this kind of issue:

Rename your controller-class to `ContactController` and the containing file to `ContactController.php` (not contactCtroller.php).

Then add a route to your `routes.php`-file

```
Route::get("contact", "ContactController@index");
```

Generally pay attentions to common conventions and codings-practices, since laravel heavyly depends on concepts such as **Convention over Configuration**.

As Lukas also pointed out it might be smart to think about switching to Laravel 5 if you are just getting startet.

Anyway, let me finish by recommending laracasts, which is how i learned using laravel. It will only take you a couple of hours to dive deeply into the laravel-universe without to much knowledge needed in advance:

1. [Laravel 4 From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch)
2. [Laravel 5 Funcamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals) (no need to go through L4 from Scratch before)

Comment: thanks for the reference, i'll follow this . but problem is still same. let me learn from your reference.

Comment: @ris what url were you calling?

Comment: @ris does it work if you rename to method to `getIndex()` (in the Controller, not in the routes file)